# Как в C++ открыть на чтение текстовый файл размером 5 и больше ГБ?

Tags: файлы, c++

Насколько я понимаю, когда файл открывается на чтение, его содержимое записывается в оперативную память. Есть ли у c++ какие-нибудь встроенные механизмы для работы с большими файлами? Может как-то можно их открывать частично или скажем хранить буфер не в оперативной памяти а в постоянной?

UPD:
Сделал вот так:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args){
    char * buffer;      
    int len = 16384;    
    long t1 = clock();

    cout << "Opening file..." << endl;

    ifstream infile("filename1", ios::in | ios::binary); 
    ofstream outfile("filename2", ios::out | ios::binary);

    if(!infile || !outfile){ 
        cout << "Can not open file!" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Done!" << endl;
    cout << "Please wait! Copying file..." << endl;

    buffer = new char[len]; 
    while (!infile.eof()){
        infile.read(buffer, len);
        if(infile.gcount()) {
            outfile.write(buffer, infile.gcount());
        }
    }

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    delete[] buffer;

    long t2 = clock();

    cout << "Done!" << endl; 
    cout << "Time: " << (t2 - t1)/1000/60 << " minut."<< endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html

Comment: А что по-вашему есть «открывается на чтение»? Если вы имеете в виду `ifstream f(filename)`, то содержимое не читается в память, разработчики стандартной библиотеки C++ ведь в здравом уме.

Comment: Хм, а я почему-то думал, что в оперативную память считывается. Ну, и на том спасибо.

Comment: @Ukeo: а если файл размером в 700М лежит на компакт-диске, открытие файла должно считывать все в память и занимать 3 минуты? а если файл на сетевом диске? а если он размером 64 Тб? а если он вообще `/dev/zero`, то есть по существу бесконечного размера? поставьте себя на место разработчиков и задайте себе эти же вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Ukeo: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, при открытии файла ты получаешь его хэндл, но в память он загружается, когда ты его считываешь. Например (fread).

Comment: То есть я могу работать с файлом и при этом его размеры меня не интересуют?

Comment: @Dms, ну, `fread`-ом можно прочесть и один байт (а можно попробовать и целый файл).

Comment: Да, можете работать, но лучше весь файл, если размер файла соизмерим с имеющейся оперативной памятью, не считывать - систему уйдет в свопинг и все. Читайте блоками.

Comment: Еще один метод работы с большими файлами - `mmap`. Этот вызов предоставляет указатель на данные файла прямо в файловом кэше системы.

Но, для очень больших файлов (а в 32-бит системе и для не очень больших), может оказаться оптимально и при использовании `mmap` обращаться к файлу по частям.